# AngularJS for Landing Pages: Sharing Assets?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use AngularJS to share assets between LPs I'm creating. And vary some based on the controller.

I've used ng-view before, but realize now that it's only good for one injection (and all scopes are in that one view).

Which is the best way to do this?

- Is there a directive I'm missing?
- Is there a way to dynamically change the controller based on the routeProvider?

I followed the [Scotch.io](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating) tutorial to do the ng-view implementation.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. How do the landings pages differ and what assets do they share? What is your route setup (both on the webserver and in Angular)?

Comment: Should check out ui-view

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: Landing pages implies that the end users are coming from another domain. If this is the case, the only sharing of resources will be in your browser cache.

Comment: Sorry I should clarify. For example of 3 landing pages share the same header/footer, but different variables within the main content. Will paste some code tomorrow but hopefully this will give you an idea of what I want to do.